Setting value in a table based on another table
There are 4 tables:
trunk,
branch,
leaf and data. The Trunk table has an IDTrunk and TrunkNumber columns. The Branch table has an IDBranch, IDTrunk and BranchNumber columns. The leaf table has a IDLeaf, IDBranch and a LeafNumber columns. The Data table has an IDData, a TrunkNumber, a BranchNumber, a LeafNumber columns and a LastEditTime column. For each table, the IDx columns are the primary keys and the xNumber columns are numbers that are shown to the user. Please note that the data table holds the user shown number, not the TBL-ID (trunk, branch, leaf ID) primary keys. As the name implies, the trunk, branch and leaf tables have a parent-child relationship and an element can have multiple children but only a single parent. The child knows its parent, through the IDx column, but the parent doesn't know its children directly. Data is only associated to a TBL-ID combination. Effectively, it means that only a leaf can have data. Data can also be associated with no leaf and the xNumber columns would contain null. Any given TBL-ID combination can only appear once.
It was noticed that when the Data table grows past 200k entries, recovering the latest Data entry for any given TBL-ID takes too much time. It was decided to add a LatestDataID column to the leaf table to speed this up. This new column would countain the IDData of the latest data entry for the associated leaf. If there is no data associated with a leaf, then it can hold -1, null or some other value that would make it obvious that it doesn't have data. It is currently set to -1 but can be changed if that causes problem. Adding the new column and updating it when new data is pushed is simple enough. The issue is that it is not known how to update the LatestDataID column when the database structure is updated. Ideally, it would have to be done with a single query. This query will be executed only once when the database structure is updated to contain this new column.
As example :
Trunk Table



IDTrunk
TrunkNumber




1
10


2
5



Branch Table



IDBranch
IDTrunk
BranchNumber




1
1
1


2
1
2



Leaf Table



IDLeaf
IDBranch
LeafNumber
LatestDataID (new column to update)




1
1
5
1


2
1
6
4


3
1
7
-1


4
1
10
5


5
2
5
7


6
2
6
-1



Data Table



IDData
TrunkNumber
BranchNumber
LeafNumber
LastEditTime




1
10
1
5
9h50


2
10
1
5
8h50


3
10
1
6
7h00


4
10
1
6
7h30


5
10
1
10
12h00


6
null
null
null
10h00


7
10
2
5
10h00



Using this query :
SELECT trunk.TrunkNumber, branch.BranchNumber, leaf.LeafNumber  
    FROM leaf  
    INNER JOIN branch ON leaf.IDBranch = branch.IDBranch  
    INNER JOIN leaf ON branch.IDTrunk = trunk.IDTrunk;

The result is



TrunkNumber
BranchNumber
LeafNumber




10
1
5


10
1
6


10
1
7


10
1
10


10
2
5


10
2
6



What should be done to update Leaf.LatestDataID properly?
--EDIT--
LastEditTime is a proper timestamp. It was written like that in the example for the sake of brevity.
--EDIT 2--
MySQL 5.7 is used. If it is simpler, a procedure could also be used.

When you generate that new ID, you could use this : SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
to get that ID and if you do that, you could add that to an update statement to insert that value into that column.  If it was all in a stored procedure and done in a transaction it should get the job done.

I think easleyfixed's idea of using using LAST_INSERT ID is a good one and eliminates the first subquery in my solution. provided that IdData is the actual mysql assigned ID for the table.  I think that is not likely the case as db IDs tend to actually be longish strings, rather than integers.  Not sure if that is true for mysql.

I am not sure how to use SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(). It always returns 0. The last inserted data might not be the last modified one so that might not be appropriate in this case anyway.

Shouldn't INNER JOIN leaf be INNER JOIN trunk?

Are you using MySQL 8.x? This will probably be easier if you can use window functions.

MySQL 5.7 is currently used. There are plans to update to a more recent version but it's not feasible in the short term unfortunately.

@MarkAinsworth, well the id can be a string, but if you are using it as a primary key its way more efficient for the id to be an incrementing integer.  But yeah if you do it in a procedure and just inserted the value if the next line is grabbing the last inserted id, you will get the value you need.

This assumes MySQL 8+. If you are still using 5.7 or earlier, it is way past time to upgrade.
This will provide the desired update based on what I understand of your question:
UPDATE leaf
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT l.IDLeaf, d.IDData,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY l.IDLeaf ORDER BY d.LastEditTime DESC) AS rn
    FROM leaf l
    JOIN branch b
        ON l.IDBranch = b.IDBranch
    JOIN trunk t
        ON b.IDTrunk = t.IDTrunk
    JOIN data d
        ON l.LeafNumber = d.LeafNumber
        AND b.BranchNumber = d.BranchNumber
        AND t.TrunkNumber = d.TrunkNumber
) latest
    ON leaf.IDLeaf = latest.IDLeaf AND latest.rn = 1
SET leaf.LatestDataID = COALESCE(latest.IDData, -1);

Here's a db<>fiddle.
We do not know how your application is interacting with the db, but it seems likely that you would be much better off fixing your data model, as opposed to introducing redundant data while the dataset is so small.
Replacing TrunkNumber, BranchNumber, LeafNumber in Data with just IDLeaf would seem like a much better option.

For MySQL < 8 you can achieve the same using user defined variables for row number and tracking previous IDLeaf:
UPDATE leaf
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT IDLeaf, IDData, @rn := IF(IDLeaf = @prevIDLeaf, @rn + 1, 1) AS rn, @prevIDLeaf := IDLeaf
    FROM (
        SELECT l.IDLeaf, d.IDData, d.LastEditTime
        FROM leaf l
        JOIN branch b ON l.IDBranch = b.IDBranch
        JOIN trunk t ON b.IDTrunk = t.IDTrunk
        JOIN data d ON l.LeafNumber = d.LeafNumber AND b.BranchNumber = d.BranchNumber AND t.TrunkNumber = d.TrunkNumber
        ORDER BY l.IDLeaf ASC, d.LastEditTime DESC  
    ) AS t
    JOIN (SELECT @prevIDLeaf := null, @rn := 0) init
) AS latest ON leaf.IDLeaf = latest.IDLeaf AND latest.rn = 1
SET leaf.LatestDataID = COALESCE(latest.IDData, -1);

Here's another db<>fiddle.

This is what I want to do but unfortunately, MySQL 5.7 is still used so it will not work.

I have added a MySQL 5.7 "friendly" version of the query.

I am not sure I understand your question, but I'm thinking an insert trigger on data or query in code that inserts data should work.  This assumes that based on your text, that there will be only 1 trunk/branch/leaf combination for a given data record
UPDATE LEAF l1 
 SET latestDataID = 
   (SELECT IDData FROM DATA d1 
     WHERE d1.LastEditTime = 
   (SELECT MAX(LastEditTime) FROM DATA d2 
      WHERE d2.TrunkNumber = d1.TrunkNumber 
      AND d2.BranchNumber = d1.BranchNumber 
      AND d2.LeafNumber= d1.LeafNumber)) 
 WHERE l1.IdLeaf= (SELECT IdLeaf FROM leaf L2
 WHERE l2.leafNumber = d1.leafnumber) 
    AND l1.idBranch = 
       (SELECT IdBranch FROM BRANCH 
        WHERE Branch.BranchNumber = d1.BranchNumber) 
    AND l1.IdTrunk = 
       (SELECT IdTrunk FROM TRUNK 
       WHERE TRUNK.TrunkNumber = d1.TrunkNumber)

Holy correlated subquery, Batman!! I THINK this will work, depending on your requirement and my lack of typo's.  But I think you would be well served to add IdLeaf, IdBranch and IdTrunk to Data and create and index on them.
I also assume that LastEditTime is an actual timestamp

I think this is a step in the right direction but I had to add an "INNER JOIN DATA d1 in the (SELECT IdLeaf FROM leaf L2 WHERE l2.leafNumber = d1.leafnumber) subquery. The last AND clause doesn't work either because the leaf table doesn't have an IDTrunk column, it has to go through the Branch table to get to that. I also think that you're right about adding the TBL-ID column to the data table but that's not really possible atm.
